# iOS How to insert two UIButton in single method programatically?

Tags: ios, uibutton

In my application I have to insert two `UIButton` in `UIView` with single method while popup appear . and i have done it but with this it always call last button  added to `subView`.

Here is my code:-

```
       int titleLabelHeight = titleLabel.frame.size.height;

        _btnManual=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, titleLabelHeight-30, popupView.frame.size.width - 16, popupView.frame.size.height - 16 - 40 - (titleLabelHeight + 16))];


        [_btnManual addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(sendBtnPressed:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_btnManual setTitle:@"Add Feed Manualy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [_btnManual setTag:1];

        [_btnManual setTitleColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:98.0f/255.0f green:42.0f/255.0f blue:101.0f/255.0f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [popupView addSubview:_btnManual ];

  _btnSearch=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, titleLabelHeight+20, popupView.frame.size.width - 16, popupView.frame.size.height - 16 - 40 - (titleLabelHeight + 16))];
       [_btnSearch addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(sendBtnPressed:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_btnSearch setTag:2];
    [_btnSearch setTitle:@"Search Data From Feed" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    [_btnSearch setTitleColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:98.0f/255.0f green:42.0f/255.0f blue:101.0f/255.0f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [popupView addSubview:_btnSearch ];

-(IBAction)sendBtnPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{

    NSLog(@"==%@",sender);
    if(sender == _btnManual)
    {
        searchfromfeed1=NO;
        [_btnManual setHidden:YES];
        [_btnSearch setHidden:YES];
        [self setupSubtitle];
        [self setuptableview];

        [self setupTextFields];
        [self setupButtons];

    }
    else if (sender == _btnSearch)
    {
        searchfromfeed1 = YES;
        [_btnManual setHidden:YES];
        [_btnSearch setHidden:YES];
        //[self setupSubtitle];
        [self setuptableview];

        [self setupTextFields];
        [self setupButtons];
    }



    }
```

but with this it always call `sender = tag2`[last button means last button added as subview].

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this problem because of overlapping. It can be solved by setting proper coordinates for both button.Please find attached image to get more idea.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        _btnManual=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - 16, 100)];

        _btnManual.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        [_btnManual addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(sendBtnPressed:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_btnManual setTitle:@"Add Feed Manualy" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_btnManual setTag:1];

        [_btnManual setTitleColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:98.0f/255.0f green:42.0f/255.0f blue:101.0f/255.0f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.view addSubview:_btnManual ];


        _btnSearch=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, _btnManual.frame.size.height+10, self.view.frame.size.width - 16, 100)];
        _btnSearch.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];

        [_btnSearch addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(sendBtnPressed:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_btnSearch setTag:2];
        [_btnSearch setTitle:@"Search Data From Feed" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        [_btnSearch setTitleColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:98.0f/255.0f green:42.0f/255.0f blue:101.0f/255.0f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.view addSubview:_btnSearch ];

        //[self.view addSubview:_popupView];

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    -(IBAction)sendBtnPressed:(UIButton*)sender
    {
        if(sender == _btnManual)
        {
            [_btnManual setHidden:YES];
            [_btnSearch setHidden:YES];


        }
        else if (sender == _btnSearch)
        {
            [_btnManual setHidden:YES];
            [_btnSearch setHidden:YES];
            //[self setupSubtitle];

        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think `btnSearch` covers `btnManual`. You could set `backgroundColor` for them or use user interface inspector in xcode. 
Check `titleLabelHeight`  value and `CGRectMake` in

```
_btnSearch=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, titleLabelHeight+20, popupView.frame.size.width - 16, popupView.frame.size.height - 16 - 40 - (titleLabelHeight + 16))];
```

[image: screen]

Answer (score 0):

Make one Common Method for Button as below,

```
-(void)ButtonFrame:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString *)buttonTitle tag:(int)buttonTag
{
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [button setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:98.0f/255.0f green:42.0f/255.0f blue:101.0f/255.0f alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(sendBtnPressed:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTag:buttonTag];
    [popupView addSubview:button];

}
```

Now you want to Calling above function two times, and adding two button with frame,

Button `_btnManual` Calling as below,

```
[self ButtonFrame:CGRectMake(8, titleLabelHeight-30, popupView.frame.size.width - 16, popupView.frame.size.height - 16 - 40 - (titleLabelHeight + 16)) title:@"Add Feed Manualy" tag:1];
```

and Same as `_btnSearch` Calling as below,

```
[self ButtonFrame:CGRectMake(8, titleLabelHeight+20, popupView.frame.size.width - 16, popupView.frame.size.height - 16 - 40 - (titleLabelHeight + 16)) title:@"Search Data From Feed" tag:2];
```

Now Click event :

```
-(IBAction)sendBtnPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if (sender.tag == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Touch on _btnManual");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Touch on _btnSearch");
    }
}
```